# Python Spark - Convert timestamp into YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

I'm currently trying to convert a timestamp into a date format of `YYYY-MM-DD` on Python Spark

Example:

```
table = random_name
start_time: 2017-03-25T12:58:16.000+0000
```

**output desired: 2017-03-25**

```
start_time: timestamp
```

Code:

```
x = spark.table(random_name)

display(x.withColumn('ts', to_timestamp(col('start_time')))
          .withColumn('new_start_date', to_date(col('ts')))
```

But I got this

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed a paranthesis at the end ")"